# Console.log() affects expression result?

Tags: javascript, expression, console.log

I encountered weird behaviour of `console.log()` in JavaScript. It might not be weird at all, but i saw it first time. It is about `console.log()` affected result of expression by doubling it.

What I'am doing is: i press buttons that should add numbers. I press "3", "2" and "1". So i should see "321". And that's what i get, when it's ok.

Situation when **all is fine**:
[image]

But when i uncomment that lower `console.log()` (at line 595), it makes the result to be "332211", when i press same buttons.

[image]

I don't understand why giving the expression from line 593, to `console.log()` affects this expression's result? I mean, I think that I should see this expression result in the console, but neither doubled in console nor doubled at the page.

**Why `console.log()` (at line 595) affected result of expression at line 593?**

Comment: You're explicitly adding `ev.target.innerHTML` to `currentInput.value`. `a += b` is just a shortcut to `a = a + b`.

Comment: Because running `a+=b` changes value of `a`.

Comment: Actually you highlighted the problematic part. Since `console.log()` is for debugging purpose, you should not alter the values of variables in the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are updating `currentInput.value` inside its invocation. If you don't want that to happen, you should replace

```
console.log('Amount of money:', currentInput.value += ev.target.innerHTML);
```

with

```
console.log('Amount of money:', currentInput.value + ev.target.innerHTML);
```

(note that `+=` is replaced with `+`).

Comment: Ok, but even though why `console.log()` affects expression made outside it? Shouldn't the result of `console.log()` be visible only in console?

Comment: @Chris92 This answer is correct - `console.log` is just a function, and the `+=` operator will _modify_ your value, whereas the simple `+` will only modify the value for the current evaluation, discarding the change afterwards.. It has nothing to with `console.log`, it has to do with the operator.

Comment: @Chris92 No because `currentInput.value` is actually being updated. Although what you intend is to just print its value, you are actually modifying it with the `+=` operator.

Comment: @Chris92 If you want a simpler case, try running this code: `x = 0; console.log(x = 2);`. It will print `2`. It's the same logic: `x` is being updated _before_ being printed.

Comment: Now I commented expression `currentInput.value += ev.target.innerHTML;` (at line 593) and I left that `console.log()` with expression inside. Then, I get same result as with only expression being executed (with commented `console.log()`). So alone `console.log(currentInput.value += ev.target.innerHTML);` did the same thing as standalone expression `currentInput.value += ev.target.innerHTML;`. is it correct?

Comment: @Chris92 It is. However, I'd suggest you to uncomment the line 593 instead of modifying `currentInput.value` at `console.log()`, because if you then remove that `console.log()` you might forget to update the value and this will cause a bug.

Comment: @LostMyGlasses I understand. Thank you for explanation!